# How to build the scoring matrix for global sequence alignment?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics, biometrics

I have tried to get the global sequence alignment between two strings. But it gives me the wrong answer.
My way of generating the scoring matrix as below.

```
public void makeScoringMatrix(String v,String w)
{
    int ar[][]=new int[v.length()+1][w.length()+1];
    for(int i=v.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=w.length()-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(v.charAt(i)==w.charAt(j))
                ar[i][j]=ar[i+1][j+1]+1;
            else if(v.charAt(i)!=w.charAt(j))
                ar[i][j]=ar[i+1][j+1]+0;
            else
                ar[i][j]=Math.max(ar[i][j+1],Math.max(ar[i+1][j],ar[i+1][j+1]));
        }
    }
    //printArray(ar);
    getGlobalAlignment(ar,v,w);
}

public void getGlobalAlignment(int ar[][],String v,String w)
{
    int i=0,j=0,index=0;
    while(i<v.length() && j<w.length())
    {
        if(v.charAt(i)==w.charAt(j))
        {
            System.out.print(v.charAt(i));
            i++;
            j++;
            index++;

        }
        else if(ar[i+1][j]>ar[i][j+1])
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }

}
```

Someone please help me...!

Comment: What is in `getGlobalAlignment` (how do you know the bug isn't there?) And can you give an example of the input and output that is the wrong answer? Otherwise it will be almost impossible to find the bug.

Comment: Click edit and put it into your question.

Comment: I have added it into the code.

Comment: And can you provide an example of an input that gives the wrong answer?

Comment: makeScoringMatrix("ATCA","AGCA");

Comment: And what wrong answer does it give for ATCA, AGCA?

Comment: why do you want to write an alignment algorithm? (i.e. why doe the existing ones not fit your needs?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

```
public void makeMatrix(String v,String w)
{
    int[][] maxDist=new int[v.length()+1][w.length()+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=v.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=w.length();j++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                maxDist[i][j]=-j;
            else if(j==0)
                maxDist[i][j]=-i;
            else
                maxDist[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    fillMatrix(maxDist, v, w);
}

public int weight(String v,String w,int i,int j)
{
    if(v.charAt(i-1)==w.charAt(j-1))
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

public void fillMatrix(int[][] ar,String v,String w)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=v.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=w.length();j++)
        {
            int scoreDiagonal=ar[i-1][j-1]+weight(v, w, i, j);
            int scoreLeft=ar[i][j-1]-1;
            int scoreUp=ar[i-1][j]-1;

            ar[i][j]=Math.max(scoreDiagonal, Math.max(scoreLeft, scoreUp));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is the code you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Your scoring matrix is incorrect. If you print the matrix you will see that it looks like this:

```
    A  T  C  A
A [3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
G [3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
C [3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
A [3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
  [3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

The problem is you are comparing v[i] to every w[j] when it should only be compared to at most 2 adjacent positions (i and i+1).

You will also notice that the last column is all 0s when it should be the first row and first column are considered to be the terminal value (which is why the matrix is length+1).

finally, I believe during the traceback for a global alignment, you should start at the final position in the matrix and walk backwards (hence the term trace-**back**.  When you walk forward over your alignment you compare the sequence similarity in the sequence, not the scores in the matrix which I don't think is correct.

You should look at the wikipedia article on Needleman-Wunsch http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm or read one of the algorithm books; Durbin et al's *Biological sequence analysis* is the classic (but very hard to understand) book that covers pairwise alignments.